# Has Microsoft ever developed a CMS?

Tags: content-management-system, umbraco, dotnetnuke

I am going to give a talk about Umbraco at the Belgium's Microsoft Innovation Center.

While preparing my speech I was wondering if Microsoft had ever developed its own CMS. Orchard is still in development and is on the verge to be released. Is Orchard the very first CMS developed by Microsoft itself? We are in 2010 did I miss something since the last 10 years when ASP.NET was released? lol

SharePoint is not a CMS. It is a collaborative platform with CMS capabilities. DotNetNuke has never been developed by Microsoft even though its chief Architect discuss technical challenges with Scott Guthries years ago. Oxite is a one shoot that has no support.

As a conclusion: Is Orchard the very first CMS that Microsoft has developed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first Microsoft CMS was IBuySpy Portal. It was originally written by Microsoft as an open source ASP.NET demonstration app but was picked up by Shaun Walker and eventually became DotNetNuke.

Microsoft also bought a product called NCompass Resolution, which was sold as Microsoft Content Management Server before being subsumed into Sharepoint 2007.

Oxite has been dropped and replaced by Orchard - after getting negative feedback, the Oxite team decided to reboot their CMS project under the Orchard name. See http://www.zdnet.com/blog/microsoft/orchard-microsofts-open-source-cms-platform-is-reborn/4506.

Comment: Thanks MarkXA your comment is very instructive :p

Answer (score 1):

Yes Microsoft has something called "Microsoft Content Management Server" but it's no longer supported. It's now replaced by Microsoft Sharepoint.

Answer (score 1):

There was the Content Managment Server

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms946812.aspx

whose functionality was later incorporated into Sharepoint server 2007.

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft Content Management Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Content_Management_Server) (around year 2002).